# Cannot set an object property with Woocommerce category list, says NULL

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the below class, which retrieves a list of product categories. When I try to set the prop $cat_list in the same method I get NULL on a var_dump of the prop. Can anyone see why?

If I set a variable inside the scope of the method collate_cats then I can var_dump that, it contains what it should but I can't set the prop using the same code.

```
class HwdmMain {

    private $pluginloc;

    //if required, this can hold the list of categories obtained
    public $cat_list = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->set_pluginloc(site_url());
    }

    private function set_pluginloc ($url) {
        $this->pluginloc = $url;
    }

    public function plugin_hooks() {
        add_action('init', [$this, 'collate_cats'], 15);
    }

    public function collate_cats () {
        $args = array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
            'hide_empty'    => false,
            'parent'        => 0
        );

        $c = get_categories($args);
        $this->cat_list = $c;
    }



} //closes the class
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. If I get rid of the method plugin_hooks and instantiate the class on 'init' instead then the collate_cats method works and sets the prop as expected. I assume it is something to do with what stage things exist at during the wordpress lifecycle.